# Magento root directory to install patch files

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, theme, css, patches

How to specify exact command for Magento patch file installation, I need to install `CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch` file it shows some errors.

`git apply --apply CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch` I use this command to install patch file where to specify magento root folder and how to do that.

`git apply public_html/pub --apply CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch` this is the command? please help me somebody..

I attach the error image[image]

This error shows at every time try to install and also tried another method

1. create patch.php upload using FTP in `public_html` folder
2. In browser called that file ex: `www.example.com/patch.php` it shows "done" text only..

I am using magento 2.1.6 then upgrade to magento 2.1.7 it solve image resize issue then try to install patch file using putty. Then I use this command `git apply --apply CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch` there is nothing to be install please somebody help me..

Answer (score 0):

As per your screen shot, you are running the command from system root but you need to go to your Magento root folder then you have to run command for applying the patch.

Like: `git apply MAGETWO-67805-2017-05-17-03-04-03.patch`

Run these commands, it will solve your CSS and JS loading issue.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: magento root folder means i don't know exactly I have app, lib,pub, setup, var, vendor folders please help me..

Comment: What is your setup path in system?

Comment: The command like "git apply public_html/pub CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch" this is the command?

Comment: setup path means public_html/setup

Comment: run php bin/magento and check output.

Comment: I run this command it shows CLI version, usage, options, available commands etc..

Comment: Now run this command : git apply MAGETWO-67805-2017-05-17-03-04-03.patch

Comment: It shows same error above attached image

Comment: Your website is working?

Comment: yes. can i send URL?

Comment: What is Magento version?

Comment: I just update magento 2.1.6 to magento 2.1.7 for product image not showing issue.

Comment: Also check my magento site in www.magereport.com it shows "No magento installation found"

Comment: Give me your site URL.

Comment: www.urbanzaveri.com

Comment: You have already upgrade magento version 2.1.6 to 2.1.7, you can't need to install this patch. Patch is only for magento-2.1.6. 

Magento 2.1.7 already installed with patch.

Comment: but some css and js not working properly as per theme. I guessed it solve by installing patch file.

Comment: I am first try to install patch file before upgrade magento 2.1.7 it shows only errors that's why i update magento 2.1.7

Comment: No, Patch can't resolve you css and js issue. Kindly run deploy command and check.

Comment: My first problem is product image resize issue and css and js not working properly beginning of theme installation then I try to install patch file then think it is version problem.

Comment: See my updated answer for it.

Comment: Also run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command many times it is not solved my issue.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: you said run deploy command right?

Comment: Just run all commands as given.

Comment: ok I tried gain those commands can you send me your email for just any need further assistance..